# Root Access on Android Things

Tags: root, android-things, xposed, xposed-framework, root-access

I bought Android Starter Kit Pico NXP i.MX7D. I'm developping an application that requires root access, in particular I have to use a particular module of xPosed framework, but it requires root permission. I have just tried to obtain the access using many root-app for Android (such as Framaroot, KingoRoot, Rootmaster, z4root, ecc.) but nothing work.

Someone knows if exist a method to accomplish my purpose?

Comment: Check if `system/xbin/su` is still there.

Comment: Yes the file is still there.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by nothing worked ? If the su binary is there I think the rooting is successful ( hard to tell from here ) there are apps such as root check that tell you if phone is rooted. XDA developers is great place to start

Comment: @Suraj, file `system/xbin/su` is available, but I tried to install SuperSu as a normal app (seeing as any kind of custom recovery doesn't exist for my device) and I get **Root Undetected**. Then I tried to copy `system/xbin/su` to `system/bin` and I pushed busybox in`system/bin`, next I lauch SuperSu but i get **SU binary occupied**. I attempt to update `su` binary installing SuperSu v.2.79 as I read in many discussions but it fails.

Comment: @matz_ I'm not updated with the android rooting these days but as you're trying to do stuff manually instead of recovery, maybe try analyzing the updater-script in supersu flashable zip. The script which has 'instructions' about flashing the zip file.

Comment: Thanks @Suraj for the tip, I have tried to install necessary files following system-install and system-less install as presented in upgrade-binary script, but the result is always the same.

Comment: HI @matz_ - any update on this? Did you manage to get root access on your i.MX7D?